# MySQL pulling get_current_user_id() on wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Just trying to pull some data linked to user ids in MySQL and cant seem to get it to pull based on whos logged in, anyone help on this?

```
SELECT
user_id, custom
FROM uwp_usermeta WHERE user_id = (current_user->ID;)
SELECT
"average" AS user_id,
avg(custom) FROM uwp_usermeta AS custom
```

I have tried get_current_user_id() wp_get_current_user_id() current_user->ID; and may variations of these codes... am I missing <?php in front of it to pun php inline? im mainly a MySQL data guy so excuse any ignorance.

Comment: [get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) should work - assuming you're trying to run this code within WordPress' environment. You'd need to provide some more details so we can actually help.

Comment: Yep its running in wordpress, within a plugin that allows me to query the database using mysql is there any specific info you need?

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your plugin would help, yes. That way anyone here could install it on a test site and see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the below way to find the required data from WordPress DB.

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$fetch_login_user_data = SELECT user_id, custom FROM uwp_usermeta WHERE user_id = ($current_user);

Comment: Cheers Mohit, but this doesnt seem to solve the matter. Tried it inline where current_user->ID; is and at the top calling current_user